# How to replace the deprecated WakefulBroadcastReceiver with JobScheduler when triggering Geofences

Tags: android, android-geofence, android-jobscheduler

I am using the WakefulBroadcastReceiver to receive events of triggering Geofences. It starts an IntentService as wakefulService. I want in some cases to wake up the device and show an Activity and in other cases to just do some really minor work without waking it up.

With Android O the WakefulBroadcastReceiver is deprecated and should be replaced with the JobScheduler. The problem is, after reading the docs and some examples I still have no idea how to do this. If the examples don't just schedule the job in a running Activity they use a BroadcastReceiver but thats exactly what im not supposed to do.

Where should i schedule the job and how can i wake up the device without using a WakefulBroadcastReceiver?